# How to read a byte in Dart.?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have below code in Java. How to implement this in Dart.?? Can someone help on this.?

```
//byte array
private byte[] data;

//read a byte
public byte readByte(){
      byte x = data[offset];
      offset ++;
      return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ByteData](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html) Class like following, this will create ByteArray of size 8, from which you can access the data by index like next line:

```
var bdata = new ByteData(8);
int huh = bdata.getInt32(0);
```